# VS1550059: Test run has been aborted because all the test agents failed during the test execution

Tags: azure-devops, performance-testing, load-testing

Hi when we are testing for load test using visual studio online, we are getting below error,

> VS1550059: Test run has been aborted because all the test agents
>   failed during the test execution
>   somebody, please help me to resolve this issue?

we are getting above error when a number of the test case. so is there any limitation for a test case on cloud load testing (visual studio online)

Comment: Do you get the error every time after running some tests? How many tests work fine?

Comment: My loadtest is not getting start when total 57 scenario are in loadtest file, however when 35 scenario are in same loadtest files, test is getting start and running properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause for this issue is that the number of scenarios is high.

The reason is -- there are few limits on the size (64KB) of the load test scenario metadata which gets stored.

Meanwhile, I would suggest the following workaround:

Shorten the names of the scenarios or reduce the number of scenarios.

I do not have the exact limits (number of scenarios, name length etc) handy right now, will get back with more details soon.

Thanks, Ganesh.

Comment: it will be great if you provide exact limits, so that we can plan accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue too, there is a feedback that you can follow. [VSTS load test, Test run has been aborted because all the test agents failed during the test execution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/79518/vsts-load-test-test-run-has-been-aborted-because-a.html).